# Repeatedly reading html and save as csv

Tags: r, loops

I need to repeatedly read (and process) an html and save as csv over 500 times. Can you please help me write a loop? For example,

```
url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/944508/000104746914007395/a2221329z424b7.htm"
write.csv(sent, "1.csv")
```

Then, read another URL and save as "2.csv", etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `sent` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing all your URL's in a vector first. After that, try this.

```
csv_names <- NULL
for(i in 1:500) csv_names[i] <- paste(as.character(i),".csv",sep="")

for(i in 1:500){
  write.csv(URL[i],file=csv_names[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step create a vector of urls:

```
url_vec<-c("url1","url2")
```

then automatically you get the vector of csv names:

```
csv_vec<-paste0(rep(1:length(url_vec)),".csv")

for(n in 1:length(url_vec)){

        [...start...] 
    (process to create csv)
         [...end...]

   write.csv(sent, csv_vec[n])
}
```